I applied an array modifier, joined the parts together, but the pieces are not connected
I feel like I've done everything to try to fix this issue (merge vertices by distance, change origin, I've tried to remesh but it ruins topology...
I made the belt using an array modifier (which I applied) the pieces act like they are one most of the time... should I be worried about how the armature will affect the belt when I add one or is this fine as is?
(see pictures below)



Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

the Array modifier has a merge option. Had you ticked it before you applied the modifier? A Merge by Distance should work, too, if the distance between the verts is not too big. You can change the distance in the popup at the bottom left corner of the viewport.

Thank you! changing the distance in the popup worked! (It was set to 0.001 for some reason...)
